# Do lwc setters fail silently by design?

Tags: lightning-web-components

If you encounter an unhandled error anywhere in an `lwc` setter, it seems to vanish into the ether. I am using `@api` setters, but I imagine it would work without that annotation. The below should be enough to reproduce.

```
_attribute;
@api
get attribute() { return _attribute; }
set attribute(value) {
    throw "Silent Error";
    _attribute = value
}
```

If you include this component in a parent somewhere, passing in any attribute value, you will see that this error does not show up in the console (nor anywhere else I can find). Is it by design that lwc setters suppress errors? Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: Don't know if this is by design or documented anywhere, but I sure have had this error before as well when trying to access the value without checking it first. Also it doesn't seem to be written anywhere in the lwc.dev website or the developer guide...

Answer (score 4):

Don't throw a naked string in LWC. While this works in standard JavaScript, those errors are caught by the render lifecycle handler, which is why they disappear. Realistically, this is probably a bug, since Error works but strings do not. I'll see about bringing this up with someone.

Instead, you want to throw an Error:

```
  _attribute;
  @api
  get attribute() { return this._attribute; }
  set attribute(value) {
    throw new Error("Silent Error");
    this._attribute = value;
  }
```

In Lightning Experience, you'll the red error window:

[image: Component Error]

In an Aura application (`aura:application`), you'll get the gray-screen error:

[image: Aura Application Error]

Elsewhere, such as LWR/LWS OSS, you'll get just a console error:

[image: WebComponents Error]

However, if you want to suppress this behavior, you can write your own error handler:

```
errorHandler(error, stack) {

}
```

However, while this will let you log the error or something, your component may unrender if you do this. **Edit:** In fact, it seems to break things even worse, as it tries to unrender a non-existent component.

It is strongly recommended that you do not attempt to throw Errors anytime during the render life cycle, as it will most likely break your app.

**Edit 2:** Also, make sure you're using your own try-catch blocks. If you control the error, you won't lose it in the framework.

Comment: Yeah throwing a string was just for demo purposes. In a more general sense, any error getting swallowed by the framework can lead to huge increases in development time trying to catch some small mistake somewhere.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yeah, hence I'm going to talk to people about it :D

Comment: Appreciate that.

Comment: The main thing really holding me back from accepting is just the emphasis the content places on the error throwing mechanism, whereas the pain comes from not knowing the real source or it being hard to find.

Comment: @AdrianLarson That's fair. I think the main point is that this appears to be some kind of bug. I'm going to try and get in touch with someone, I'll circle back around when I have more information.